# Image editing in Android

Tags: java, android

In my application image editor I want to implement image brightness, contrast, sharpness, zooming, rotating, and save the image to my gallery.

Comment: LOL the question mark is not the problem here. He basically wants SO to write the app for him.

Answer (score 1):

If you are look for a place to start take a look at canvas.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

The basic classes you need is `Canvas`, `Bitmap` and `Matrix`.

For example, to rotate and/or scale (zoom?) an image:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
matrix.setScale(scaleFloatX, scaleFloatY);

// And apply it to photo image
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

For more advanced operations (brightness etc.) you can look here: [Android image sharpening, saturation, hue, brightness, and contrast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462920/android-app-image-editing-through-sharpening-saturation-hue-brightness-and-c)

To store the image you need to do something like this:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, bitmap, "mybitmap", "stacko"));
```