# Making a low res image look good

Tags: android

I'm displaying images from various of sources, and can't control the quality I get, I want to display all images in same size and make them look good no matter how small they are.
Is there a filter, magic effect, whatever I can do to the image to make it look good?

Comment: What is small for you?

Comment: an actual example of the image would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You mean fitting a low-resolution image into a large frame size and still look good and sharp? Android doesn't have this magic. Sorry

Comment: I know there are no magics... it shouldn't look sharp.. just looking for a good enough algorithm to make it look nice..

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a blur effect on your image, which is what most modern browsers and image viewers do nowadays in order not just to show a big block of pixels - not sure what your scenario is though (native or HTML5 app ? Are the images bundled into the app or are you loading online resources?)...

For starters, here's a nice [tutorial on different blur techniques incl. java code samples](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html) (Found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462920/android-image-sharpening-saturation-hue-brightness-and-contrast)).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing Android comes with is to use paint.setFilterBitmap(true) for the paint you use to draw the bitmap.